# In PHP how can I read subvalue of an XML line?

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML line from a XML file:

```
<issue>
  <host ip="10.10.5.6">http://www.testing.com</host>
```

It is clear that I can read the host (http://www.testing.com) like this:

```
$simple = file_get_contents('/directory/test1.xml');
$test = new SimpleXMLElement($simple);
echo $test ->issue[1]->host;
```

But how can I read host ip (10.10.5.6) ?

Thank you for the help!

---

Solution: echo $test ->issue[1]->host[ip];

Comment: that's an "attribute", not a "sub-value".

Comment: Thank you Mark, I will look at the question linked.